# When the main window remains at the top, the child Windows are occluded - MacOS

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Usually, the tools window is always at the top of the main window, even if it loses focus. However.

On MacOS, when the main window sets the window flag `Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint`, the Tool window is below it.

On a Windows system, the Tool window is at the top of the main window as expected.

Is there a way to keep the main window at the top while the Tool window is above it?

[image]

My current Qt versions are 5.9.6 and 5.12.1.
The MacOS version is 10.13.4.

This is my test code

```
#include <QtGui>
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QDialog* mw = new QDialog(0, Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint | Qt::X11BypassWindowManagerHint);
    mw->setWindowTitle(QLatin1String("Main"));
    mw->resize(400, 300);
    mw->move(100, 100);

    QWidget* d = new QWidget(mw, Qt::Tool);
    d->setWindowTitle(QLatin1String("Tool"));
    d->resize(200, 100);
    d->show();
    mw->exec();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, I have no MacOS system, however, I could reproduce and fix your problem under Ubuntu. Hopefully, it will work the same under MacOS.

First, bnaecker is right, you should call `show()` rather than `exec()` for your main window. Would be nice if it was a `QMainWidget` rather than a `QDialog`, but that's not the problem here.

According to the doc:

> Qt::Tool: Indicates that the widget is a tool window. A tool window is
>   often a small window with a smaller than usual title bar and
>   decoration, typically used for collections of tool buttons. It there
>   is a parent, the tool window will always be kept on top of it. If
>   there isn't a parent, you may consider using Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint
>   as well. If the window system supports it, a tool window can be
>   decorated with a somewhat lighter frame. It can also be combined with
>   Qt::FramelessWindowHint.

Your tool widget, has a parent, so that should work. However, by testing, I can see that the tool's window should be shown when the tool itself is shown for it to remain on top as expected...that's strange, but that's what I observe.

Also, I noticed that `Qt::X11BypassWindowManagerHint` messes things up...

Finally, by combining those observations + bnaecker reply, the code is:

```
#include <QtGui>
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    // don't set Qt::X11BypassWindowManagerHint if you want the tool to stay on top!
    QDialog* mw = new QDialog(0, Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);// | Qt::X11BypassWindowManagerHint);
    mw->setWindowTitle(QLatin1String("Main"));
    mw->resize(400, 300);
    mw->move(100, 100);

    // show main window before tool is shown
    mw->show();

    QWidget* d = new QWidget(mw, Qt::Tool);
    d->setWindowTitle(QLatin1String("Tool"));
    d->resize(200, 100);
    d->show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Now, "Tool" window is on top of "Main" dialog and there's no way for it to be hidden by its parent.

Note that this work regardless if you specify or not `Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint` flag for the "Main" window. This flag has no effect on the fact that "Tool" remains on top of "Main". This makes "Main" (and so "Tool") be on top of any other application's window.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work.When the main window gains focus, the Tool window is overwritten. My current Qt versions are 5.9.6 and 5.12.1.The MacOS version is 10.13.4.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're calling `QDialog::exec`, rather than directly about the window hints. The `exec` method for a dialog shows it as a *modal* dialog, which means interaction with any other window in the application is not allowed until the user closes the dialog. Changing `mw->exec()` into `mw->show()` will demonstrate that the tool window can indeed be brought on top of the main window, regardless of the window hint.

You might consider using a main window that is *not* a `QDialog` (which is an uncommon situation). Dialogs are intended to block the user from continuing with the normal use of the application until answering a question or acknowledging something (such as an error). They are not usually thought of as the main window through which a user interacts with an application. Using another subclass of `QWidget`, such as `QMainWindow` or even just a plain `QWidget` with the `Qt::Window` flag set, might be more appropriate.

Comment: However, when the main window is clicked, the Tool window will still be overwritten.

Comment: I am very sorry that my expression is not clear enough.Normally, the Tool window will always be at the top of the main window, even if it loses focus.However, when the Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint flag is set in the main window, the Tool window is no longer always located at the top of the main window.

Comment: @郭德纲 Yes, that's right. I'm not sure I understand your point. The goal of that hint is to do exactly that, keep the window on top of all others. If that's not what you want, you'll need to remove the flag.

Comment: I hope that the main window stays above other Windows, while the Tool window stays above the main window. Is it possible to achieve this on MacOS?

Comment: I don't believe that's possible. You could override the main window's event handlers, such as `focusInEvent`, so that they always call `raise()` on the tool window. But I think this will be both complicated and only make it so that the tool is *usually* on top, not always. I have to ask, why do you want this behavior? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @myxingkong: "I hope that the main window stays above other Windows, while the Tool window stays above the main window". That's what I observe with the code I posted with my answer.